# obtain exponential inequality using symmetric random variables and rademacher random variables

Tags: statistics, inequality, rademacher-distribution

I'm new to mathematical stats and came here to get some help for my homework problem in advanced statistics.

The problem is:

Let $X_1, \cdots, X_n$ be independent, not necessarily identical random variables. Assume that each $X_i$ is symmetric, meaning that $X_i  \overset{d}{\equiv} -X_i$. Prove that $P \left[ \dfrac{\sum X_i}{\sqrt{\sum X^2_i}} \geq t \right] \leq e^{-t^2/2}, \forall t>0$.

The problem gives hint that we could use rademacher random variable $\epsilon$ using the fact that $X \overset{d}{\equiv}\epsilon X$. There are no distributional assumptions on random variables $X_i$. 
Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symmetrization hint can be used in the following way: if $\varepsilon_1, \ldots, \varepsilon_n$ are i.i.d. Rademacher random variables (independent of $X_1, \ldots, X_n$), we have
$$
P\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\ge t\|X\|_2\right)=P\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \varepsilon_i X_i \ge t\| X\|_2\right).
$$
Now we can think about $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ being fixed vectors, and look only at the randomness over $\varepsilon_1, \ldots, \varepsilon_n$. For example, using the formalism of conditional expectations,
$$
P\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \varepsilon_i X_i \ge t\| X\|_2\right)=\mathbb E\left[P\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \varepsilon_i X_i \ge t\| X\|_2\,\middle|\, X\right)\right].
$$
Now to bound the inner term, we can apply [Hoeffding's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality#General_case_of_bounded_random_variables) to $\sum_i Y_i$, where each $Y_i=\varepsilon_i X_i$ is bounded in absolute value by $|X_i|$ (recall that now, all the $X_i$'s are fixed). Hence,
$$
P\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \varepsilon_i X_i \ge t\| X\|_2\,\middle|\, X\right)\le \exp(-t^2/2),
$$
and we can take expectations on both sides.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have some questions for your answer. 1. What does it mean 'using conditional expectations'? Because this problem is about probability not expections, I cannot find point where I can apply expections. 2. Hoeffding inequliaty requires bounded random variables but in this case, there are no clues that $X_i$ are bounded. In this situation, can we apply Hoefdding inequality?

Comment: @user512412: 1/ the probability of an event can be written as the expectation of an indicator, so the concept of the conditional probability with respect to a random variable also makes sense. An intuitive way to see this in my updated answer is that the inner probability is with respect to the randomness over $\varepsilon$, whereas the outer expectation is with respect to $X$

Comment: @user512412: 2/ I need a version of Hoeffding where each summand is bounded is an interval $[a_i,b_i]$ that depends on $i$ (here, $[a_i, b_i]=[-X_i,+X_i]$). Once again, here $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are deterministic and the randomness is over $\varepsilon$

Comment: Thank you very much for kindly explaining what I asked. Still, I have uncleared points abount applying Hoeffding inequality. Letting $Y_i = \epsilon_i X_i$, $Y_i \in [-X_i, +X_i]$ with $X_i$ fixed. After applying Hoefdding inequality, I got $P \left( \sum \epsilon_i X_i \geq t || X ||_2 \mid X \right) \leq exp(-2t^2 / \sum (2X_i)^2)$. Could you give me some more details about the terms $\sum X^2_i$ in RHS exponential?

Comment: @user512412: If you have a $t\| X\|_2$ as a tail parameter in the left-hand side, then you should plug in $t\| X\|_2$ in the right-hand side as well (so it simplifies with the denominator)

Comment: Oh, that was my foolish mistake. Thank you very much again for your kind answer!